# How to encode a string in base64 in JScript

Tags: windows, jscript, wsh

Well, i think the title is pretty clear, how to encode a string to base64 in JScript?

While researching online i found this:

[How to decode a Base64 string in JScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53672996/how-to-decode-a-base64-string-in-jscript)

Yeah, intresting (for Decoding), but im not getting many other documentation and so i dont know how to encode a string.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247261/692942)? It might not work because JScript is based on ECMAScript v3.

Comment: You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11524268/692942) useful.

Comment: The first one isnt working because JScript isnt JavaScript and doesnt not provide btoa() and atob(), the second one should work, but im sure there is a way to encode a base64 just by calling a function, like for decoding, so i think there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Like I said, it might not work. As for a native function in JScript, pretty sure one doesn’t exist but [check for yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/yek4tbz0(v=vs.84)).

Comment: JScript in IE 10 and above does support `btoa` and `atob`. You must have been running your code in a lower document mode. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76112829/15764378).